# How to extract all values of a node in xml using xml parser in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an `XML` file in visual studio using `C#` and would like to store the `attributes` (individually for further use) of each node. The `XML` file is shown below:

```
<FBType GUID="123" Name="plcStart" Comment="Composite Function Block Type" Namespace="abc">
  <Attribute Name="Configuration.FB.IDCounter" Value="1" />
  <Identification Standard="123" />
  <VersionInfo Organization="org" Version="0.0" Author="sb" Date="8/23/2013" Remarks="template" />
  <InterfaceList>
    <EventInputs>
      <Event Name="ACK" />
    </EventInputs>
    <EventOutputs>
      <Event Name="START" />
    </EventOutputs>
  </InterfaceList>
</FBType>
```

I wrote the code below but I just retrieve the second three nodes and their `attributes`. I tried the part of the code that is commented now, but it didn't work.
I would be thankful for any help.

```
try
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
    {

        //foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        //{

        for (int i = 0; i < node.Attributes.Count; i++)
        {
            string atr = node.Attributes[i].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name + "   " + atr);
        }
        //}
        foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < node.ChildNodes.Count; j++)
            {

                string childName = child.Attributes[j].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(childName);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: Have you considered deserializing it with the `XmlSerializer`? You can generate the class structure using sites such as [Xml2CSharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to parse the data with DOM and store the extracted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq you can flatten results to on class object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication152
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<FBTType> fBTTypes = doc.Descendants("FBType").Select(x => new FBTType()
            {
                guid = (string)x.Attribute("GUID"),
                typeName = (string)x.Attribute("Name"),
                comment = (string)x.Attribute("Comment"),
                ns = (string)x.Attribute("Namespace"),
                name = (string)x.Element("Attribute").Attribute("Name"),
                value = (string)x.Element("Attribute").Attribute("Value"),
                identification = (string)x.Element("Identification").Attribute("Standard"),
                organization = (string)x.Element("VersionInfo").Attribute("Organization"),
                version = (string)x.Element("VersionInfo").Attribute("Version"),
                author = (string)x.Element("VersionInfo").Attribute("Author"),
                date = (DateTime)x.Element("VersionInfo").Attribute("Date"),
                remarks = (string)x.Element("VersionInfo").Attribute("Remarks"),
                eventInputs = x.Descendants("EventInputs").FirstOrDefault().Elements("Event").Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name")).ToArray(),
                eventOutputs = x.Descendants("EventOutputs").FirstOrDefault().Elements("Event").Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name")).ToArray(),
            }).ToList();

            foreach (FBTType fbTType in fBTTypes)
            {
                fbTType.print();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class FBTType
    {
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string typeName { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string ns { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string identification { get; set; }
        public string organization { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string[] eventInputs { get; set; }
        public string[] eventOutputs { get; set; }

        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GUID : '{0}'",guid);
            Console.WriteLine("Type Name : '{0}'",typeName);
            Console.WriteLine("Comment : '{0}'",comment);
            Console.WriteLine("Namespace : '{0}'",ns);
            Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}'",name);
            Console.WriteLine("Value : '{0}'",value);
            Console.WriteLine("Identification : '{0}'",identification);
            Console.WriteLine("Organization : '{0}'",organization);
            Console.WriteLine("Version : '{0}'",version);
            Console.WriteLine("Author: '{0}'",author);
            Console.WriteLine("Date : '{0}'",date.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Remarks : '{0}'",remarks);
            Console.WriteLine("Event Inputs : '{0}'",string.Join(",", eventInputs));
            Console.WriteLine("Envent Outputs : '{0}'", string.Join(",", eventOutputs));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems really cool. 
I was trying to print the first element of the list 
Console.WriteLine(fBTTypes[0]);
but I got this result:
XML_Parser_Test_05.FBTType

I'm new to c# and just migrated from java so I would be grateful if you could tell me how should I print each element on the console.